# Sort Folders in document Library

Tags: document-library, folder, sorting

need some help. i have a folder structure in numerical order but it's not appearing in numerical order the way i like, probably because of the numbering. Any tips on how to show it as 1.1, 1.2,1.3?

Thanks
Jon
[image]

Comment: I found out the answer. i created a separate table and entered the numbers as 01, 02, 03 which fixed the issue.